# Hide and show ckeditor toolbar

Tags: ckeditor

I want hide and show ckeditor toolbar on demand
how to hide Ckeditor toolbar onLoad? and first only show editor without toolbar then load as require?

Answer (score 1):

You can show and hide the toolbar menu like this
"config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;"

Is this that you wanted ?

You have to integrate it like this

```html
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {     
              
              height: 600,
         
              toolbarCanCollapse : true,                  

              allowedContent: true, 
                        
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: I edit my post to explain you how to apply this code.

Comment: Refer to the documentation here : http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_interface

Comment: The code doesn't work because you wrote `toolbarCanCollapse = true` while the correct is `toolbarCanCollapse: true`